# Oracle 10g Database Date Conversion to 'yyyy-iw' problems?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm not sure if this is a question or more of an exploration of a possible bug or a question about a better way to do handle this.

I have a rollup report that uses the

```
select column1id, column2date
from table1
where to_char(column2date,'yyyy-iw') = to_char(to_date('2012-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-iw')
```

The line: `to_char(to_date('2012-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-iw')` is converting to 2012-01, wrapping back to the beginning of the year.

Digging a bit further I find that the date 2012-12-31 is neither included in week: 2012-52 nor is it included in 2013-01, and 2012-53 doesn't return any data either... so I'm at a loss of what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=995899
**Ravi Kumar** wrote: you need to use IYYY in format.
**BluShadow** wrote: ... When it calculates the YYYY and IW these are independant of each other so it won't reduce the YYYY output to [2013] just because you have included IW in the format mask. It looks at components of the mask and not the whole thing in combination.

```
select to_char(to_date('2012-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd'),'iyyy-iw') from dual;
```

returns 2013-01.

I think your WHERE clause should be:

```
where to_char(column2date,'iyyy-iw') = to_char(to_date('2012-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd'),'iyyy-iw')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm Mathew. Thank you!